# CRTP base private constructor and derived friend class cause compilation error using C++17 and uniform initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, crtp

I've got the following code:

```
struct B
{
  B(int) {}
};

template <typename T>
class Base : public B
{
  friend T;
  Base() : B(1) {}
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    void do_sth() const {}
};

int main()
{
  auto x = Derived{}; //Compiles only when using C++11
  auto x1 = Derived(); //Compiles using C++17/20 flag
  x.do_sth();
  x1.do_sth();
}
```

For some reason when using C++17 compilation fails due to 'non-compilable' initialization of 'x' variable. Compilator says that:

> Base::Base() [with T = Derived]' is private within this context

but as you can see, below I'm creating an object of the same type but this time I'm not using uniform initialization.
x1 variable can be compiled using both C++11 or C++17 standards, but the 'x' variable is compilable only in C++11 mode. Why is that? What has changed in the standard that causes this problem?

[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/3rn63EY48)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently `Derived` is an aggregate since C++17, so `Derived{}` is an aggregate initialization. (Base classes [weren't allowed in aggregates pre-C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), now public non-virtual bases are allowed.)

Meaning `Base::Base()` is invoked directly by the caller (`main()`), rather than `Derived`.

The solution is to add `Derived() {}` to `Derived` to stop it from being an aggregate.

Comment: Or add a dummy `private: int nothing;` to `Derived`. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization): *no private or protected direct (since C++17)non-static data members*

Comment: @AdrianMole You can, but that wastes space.

Comment: The following page also explains this in some more details: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2021/07/17/extended-aggregate-initialisation-in-c17/

Comment: Well, what if I wanted to keep this type as an aggregate and at the same time have some mechanism as above that would prevent the wrong type from being passed to the base class? Is it even feasible?

Comment: @bielu000 You can `static_assert` on `std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>` somewhere in `Base`. Probably inside of a method, I don't think it'll work at class scope.

Comment: Yes, but if I use this solution, then the problem remains. Eg. one could create class Derived_1 : public Base<Derived_2> - Derived_2 also derives from Base, so static_assert will pass. So I guess that's the tradeoff - class could remain an aggregate but with a risk that somebody would use it in the wrong way.